# Prove that $\sqrt{x+y+z}\ge{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{z-1}}$.

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z>1$ such that $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=2$. Prove that

$$\sqrt{x+y+z}\ge{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{z-1}}$$.

I took $x=\sec^2{a}$, $y=\sec^2{b}$, $z=\sec^2{c}$ but it was not useful. Then I took $x-1=a$ and similarly $b$ and $c$. On simplifying I got
$$b+1\ge{2\sqrt{ac}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Applying Cauchy the following is true. $$(x+y+z)(\frac{x-1}{x}+\frac{y-1}{y}+\frac{z-1}{z})\ge (\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{y-1}+\sqrt{z-1})^2$$

However, $\frac{x-1}{x}+\frac{y-1}{y}+\frac{z-1}{z}=1$ from the condition in the problem.

$\therefore$ $\sqrt{x+y+z}\ge \sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{y-1}+\sqrt{z-1}$.

However $\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{y-1}+\sqrt{z-1}\ge \sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{z-1}$. Our proof is done.

Comment: Nice solution. However why do you say "It is obvious from Cauchy..." when you could just say "Applying Cauchy's Inequality..." or something of the sort and not talk down to the reader?

Comment: @ I. Cavey Oh, sorry. Poor choice of words. I was trying to right in a hurry. I edited the solution. I did not mean anything by it. I am not very experienced with writing down solutions in English.